# Responsive columns in Safari

Tags: css, safari, responsive-design, retina-display, yui-pure-css

I created a site using Pure.css. It seems to work fine on everything I want it to, except Safari (on my friends MBPr to be exact)

On every browser I test it on, I get this:
http://www.coflash.com/stuff/whatiget.jpg

When he tests it on Safar on his retina Macbook, he gets this:
http://www.coflash.com/stuff/whathegets.jpg

The URL is
http://www.phill.com.au/work/commsec/

Is this due to a rounding error? I don't have a Retina Macbook so I can't test, I only have Windows :/

If I can pinpoint what the issue might be I'll have a better chance of fixing it and asking him to take a look again. At the moment I can't find a thing on this issue.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 divs side by side both class="pure-u-1-2" width 50%.
In one div you have a img widht=440.
So what happens when the screen is smaller than 880?
Maybe there is the point.
(just looked on it with FF - have no Mac).
Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

One potential issue is that retina displays don't return the actual pixel count for media queries. They return half the pixel count, and set the `pixel-ratio` to 2x.